# Obtener variables miembro no privadas en Python

Tags: python, self

En una clase de Python tengo definidos los siguientes atributos (hay más, pero para ejemplificar llegan así):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.right = None       #True or false if gaze.is_right()
    self.time_right = 0     #Time looking to the right

    #Only internal
    #Internal time
    self._time_init = 0      #Datetime the program starts (used to calculate ratios and percentages)
    #Distraction intern information
    self._previous_state_right = True
    self._t_right = 0
```

Y mi intención es devolverlos al programa principal para pasarlos después a una red SOM y me preguntaba si habría alguna manera de que los atributos que son marcados como `#Only internal` se pudieran trabajar en todas las funciones de la clase, pero si hago un

```
object.__dict__
```

No me los devuelva al programa principal.

Comment: Python no tiene nada similar a "atributos privados" y te diría que los comentarios no forman parte del código a ejecutar (por lo que no son accesibles en tiempo de ejecución). Tendrás que hacer un filtro. Por ejemplo, generar un nuevo diccionario sin los atributos que empiesen con "_". Los atributos de esta caracteristica indican, por convención, que son de uso interno y no deberían ser modificados por terceros (es solo una convención, no existe ninguna restricción real)

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias, así lo haré entonces. Crearé un nuevo diccionario. Sabes si se puede hacer Override a la función o tengo que crear una nueva?

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres. Si estás creando una subclase de algo, entonces seguro podés hacer un override, incluso podes llamar a la función original en cualquier punto de la función con `super().función(...)` (si solo tiene una superclase) o `clase.funcion(self, ...)`. Si lo que me preguntas, es como hacer un override del atributo `__dict__`, es ironico, pero Python sí tiene protegidos esos atributos a pesar de que el usuario final no puede proteger nada. Mi recomendación, es que hagas una [propiedad](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#property) llamada `dict`.

Comment: Me corrijo, en realidad, `__dict__` puede ser modificado para establecer un nuevo valor o convertido en una propiedad. Pero puede ser engañoso, ya que se supone que este atributo devuelve el diccionario de todos los atributos modificables de la clase. Se supone que el diccionario devuelto, al ser modificado, también modifique los atributos de la clase. No es buena idea reemplazarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más seguro que puedes hacer es una función `diccionario` que devuelva los atributos no privados.
Cualquier manipulación poco habitual de `__dict__` puede tener consecuencias imprevisibles.
Basta con iterar todos los atributos del objeto y devolver aquellos que no empiecen por `_`.

```
def diccionario(self):
    return {nombre: valor for nombre, valor in vars(self).items()
            if nombre[0] != '_'}
```